# Custom Gutenberg Block freeform content disappears randomly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to solve an issue where I have content within a custom gutenberg block disappearing seemingly randomly (I haven't quite found the trigger yet)

See code below:

```
export default registerBlockType(
    'biscuit/content-filter',
    {
        title: __( 'Title', 'biscuit' ),
        description: __( 'Story content block.', 'biscuit'),
        category: 'common',
        icon: icons.classic,
        keywords: [
            __( 'Content', 'biscuit' ),
            __( 'Story', 'biscuit' ),
        ],
        transforms: {
            from: [
                {
                    type: 'block',
                    blocks: [ 'core/paragraph' ],
                    transform: function ( attributes ) {
                        const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.rawHandler({
                            innerContent: attributes.content
                        });
                        return wp.blocks.createBlock( 'biscuit/content-filter', {
                        }, innerBlocks );
                    },
                },
            ]
        },
        edit: props => {
            const { attributes: { title }, className, setAttributes } = props;
            return (
                <div className={ className }>
                    <div>
                        <RichText
                            tagName="h3"
                            value={ title }
                            onChange={ title => setAttributes({ title })}
                            placeholder={__('Enter title', 'biscuit')}
                            // keepPlaceholderOnFocus={ true }
                        />
                        <label class="small">{ __( 'Title will only appear on the page.', 'biscuit' ) }</label>
                    </div>Content', 'biscuit' ) }</label></h4>
                    <InnerBlocks template={TEMPLATE} templateLock="all" />
                </div>
            );
        },
        save: props => {
            return <InnerBlocks.Content />;
        },
    },
);

const setExtraPropsToBlockType = (props, blockType, attributes) => {
    if( props.children && blockType.name === 'core/freeform' ) {
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<p><!-- \/wp:paragraph --> <!-- wp:paragraph --><\/p>/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<p><!-- wp:paragraph --><\/p>/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<p><!-- \/wp:paragraph --><\/p>/g,"");

        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- wp:paragraph -->/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- \/wp:paragraph -->/g,"");

        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;\/p&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;p&gt;/g,"");

        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!-- wp:paragraph --&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!-- \/wp:paragraph --&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!– wp:paragraph –&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!– \/wp:paragraph –&gt;/g,"");

        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- wp:quote -->/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- \/wp:quote -->/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!-- wp:quote --&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!-- \/wp:quote --&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!– wp:quote –&gt;/g,"");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/&lt;!– \/wp:quote –&gt;/g,"");

        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- wp:/g,"<!--");
        props.children = props.children.replace(/<!-- \/wp:/g,"<!--");

    }
    return props;
};

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'biscuit/content-filter',
    setExtraPropsToBlockType
);
```

Sometimes the freeform will decide to empty on random posts. There seems to be no correlation with content.
I can jump into post revisions and go back and find the content that was originally posted, so at least I have that.

I have done testing on a staging site by:

- Creating a new post
- Adding the custom block and inputting the same text from a disappeared freeform block
- Adding other blocks - quote, paragraph, image etc to see if saving new content outside the block triggered it
- Duplicating any other elements from an affected post

None of these have triggered it yet. The block can disappear anywhere from 1 month to a year later. I suspect it has something to do with editing/saving the post, however I've tested this and it does not trigger.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The opening `<h4>` and `<label>` tags are missing on line 40 in `edit()`:

```js
</div>Content', 'biscuit' ) }</label></h4>
```

Replace with:

```js
</div><h4><label>{__('Content', 'biscuit')}</label></h4>
```

I would assume at some point the block was valid and the first part of line 40 was accidentally removed. This scenario could create the side effects you're seeing: most posts containing the block are valid but some that were edited when the block became invalid have issues.

Once you've made the change, make sure to clear browser cache before testing. Check the browser console for any errors and if there are, please add them to the question.